# Why there is no @Html.RouteAction(routeName: "MyRouteName") helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I like to use the strongly defined routes like

`@Html.RouteLink("Home", RouteName.HomeIndex)`

Why there is no equivalent helper for child actions? I don't like the actual `@Html.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues)` helper.

In addition, the performance would be better. There is no need to check all routes internal in the RouteCollection.

Comment: Write your own? You're fully free to do so. =)

Comment: I know, but i was wondering, why such a basic function isn't implemented in the MVC-Framework itself. I thought there's a reason for it...

Answer (score 1):

Contribute your idea and even the helper at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/ - it's open source.

The answer to Why isn't there one is that either:

1. Nobody thought of it yet
2. Someone thought of it but didn't do anything about it
3. Someone thought of it but thought better of it - for example because a route can be very general and you would need to supply controller, action and routevalues for most routes, which means the Action helper works fine.

In terms of performance, I've not had any problems with the performance of `Html.Action` so you might want to measure it before you get too concerned about optimising this aspect of the framework.